# Why does the WriteCSV component output not work in Gravio?

Tags: iot, platform

When executing the WriteCSV component in the [gravio.com](https://www.gravio.com) platform, I am getting the

> Exception WriteCSV: No output specified!

error. What could possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that you have carried the variables over using the Transponse icon:

[image]

This is how it looks correctly:

[image]